# Hide and show HTML elements using CSS based on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using vanilla HTML, Javascript and preferably just pure CSS I'm trying to implement a feature whereby when a user clicks a button, the next 4 elements are displayed to the user.

Due to limitations in the snippet, the styles aren't quite reflective - as I've implemented a grid system, so there's actually 4 items in a row (they're just horizontal in the above).

By default I want to show just 4 items, but when the user selects "load more", then the next 4 are displayed & so on. The button should always remain just below the last visible element.

Can anyone guide or reference an approach that would achieve this result?

```css
.container {
  padding: 16px;
}

.items-container {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  gap: 16px;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 320px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items-container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Showing 4 of 10</p>
  <button>
    Load more
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't meaning to be lazy or expect someone to write up a complete solution for me. My thinking was toggling `display: none` with the onClick but of course I should have showed my original attempt, I was just trying to declutter the question. I had hoped someone would perhaps link me a starting point but definitely not my intention to abuse people's kindness. Sorry again.

Comment: Yep, my bad entirely. Will do better in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do? Explanation: `updateCount` writes the current count to the `p` element. `updateItems` changes the display property of your items based on the current value of `count`. The event listener on the button increases the value of the current count by 4 and then calls the `updateItems` function, which updates the styles based on the current count and then calls the `updateCount` function to write the current page to the `p`. I hope this helps!

```js
const items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.item'));
let count = 4;

function updateCount() {
  document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = 'Showing ' + count + ' of ' + items.length;
}

function updateItems() {
  for (let index = 0; index < count; index++) {
    items[index].style.display = '';
  }

  for (let index = count; index < items.length; index++) {
    items[index].style.display = 'none';
  }

  updateCount();
}

updateItems();

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  count += 4;
  count = count > items.length ? items.length : count;
  updateItems();
});
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 16px;
}

.items-container {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  gap: 16px;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 320px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items-container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <button>
    Load more
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't write complete solutions for questions that have shown no effort. It encourages laziness.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? If you are only showing the 1st 4 elements at the start then the rest needs to be hidden until you press the button.

Once you press it, loop thru all hidden elements and remove the class which hiddes those elements `d-none` in this example and change your text from `Showing 4 of 8` to `Showing 8 of 8` with `textContent`

```js
const load = document.getElementById("load");
const divs = document.getElementsByClassName("d-none");
const showing = document.getElementById("showing");
load.addEventListener("click", function(){
    Array.from(divs).forEach((ele) => {
    // Do stuff here
    ele.classList.remove("d-none");
  });
  showing.textContent = "Showing 8 of 8";
})
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 16px;
}

.items-container {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  gap: 16px;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 320px;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items-container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item d-none"></div>
    <div class="item d-none"></div>
    <div class="item d-none"></div>
    <div class="item d-none"></div>
  </div>
  <p id="showing">Showing 4 of 8</p>
  <button id="load">
    Load more
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't write complete solutions for questions that have shown no effort. It encourages laziness.

Comment: @isherwood understood, the answer doesn't completely answer the OPs question tho as I'm just assuming he has 8 elements. It won't work with dynamic number of elements

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you already have the elements loaded, if not, the solution  I’m going to give you won’t work completely:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Filter Testing</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            padding: 16px;
        }

        .items-container {
            flex-direction: row;
            display: flex;
            gap: 16px;
        }

        .item {
            flex: 0 0 auto;
            width: 25%;
            background-color: lightblue;
            height: 320px;
        }

        .hidden-item {
            display: 'none';
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="items-container">
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="hidden-item"></div>
            <div class="hidden-item"></div>
            <div class="hidden-item"></div>
            <div class="hidden-item"></div>
            <div class="hidden-item"></div>
            <div class="hidden-item"></div>
            <div class="hidden-item"></div>
            <div class="hidden-item"></div>
            <div class="hidden-item"></div>
            <div class="hidden-item"></div>
            <div class="hidden-item"></div>
            <div class="hidden-item"></div>
        </div>
        <p>Showing 4 of 10</p>
        <button id="loadMoreButton">
            Load more
        </button>
    </div>
    <script>
        //Let save the button reference 
        let loadMoreButton = document.getElementById('loadMoreButton');
        // Save the hidden items
        //Create an array to iterate, because the querySelector return a node list
        function loadMoreItems() {
            let hiddenItems = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden-item');
            let displayedItems = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
            Array.from(hiddenItems).forEach(function (item, index) {
                //Lets load just 4 more items
                //Remember the array init count in 0, so 3 is the 4 element loaded
                if (index < 4) {
                    //Lets remove the class to hide the element and add the class tho dsiplayed elements
                    item.classList.remove('hidden-item');
                    item.classList.add('item');
                }
            });
        }
        // Add the loadMoreItems to button
        loadMoreButton.addEventListener('click', loadMoreItems);
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).